# How to get the user viewpoint from a rotation matrix?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing an Android VR video player. My approach is using the panoramic video frame as a texture, and bind it to a sphere located at the origin point. I am using rotation vector sensor to get rotation matrix, then I pass the matrix to opengl to render the sphere. Now my question is, is there any possibility to know the latitude and longitude of the point where the user is looking at from the rotation matrix? Suppose the user starts looking at (0,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a direction vector `x`, `y`, `z`, then the longitude is:

```
longitude = Math.toDegrees( Math.atan2(-y, x) );
```

And the latitude is:

```
latitude = Math.toDegrees( Math.atan2(z, Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)) );
```